# Tomcat 8.5 can't load @WebServlet annotations

Tags: java, mapping, servlet, tomcat8

I want to transfer my web application from `tomcat7` / `java7` to `tomcat 8.5` / `java8`.
My application consists of a directory with some JSP files & WEB-INF folder which contains my application's `web.xml` :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
      version="3.1"
      metadata-complete="false">
      ...
</web-app>
```

& here is part of tomcat virtual host config:

```
<Host name="my-domain.ir" appBase="/path/to/my/webapp" >
    <Context path="" docBase="base-dir" 
     xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" crossContext="false" reloadable="false" >
    ...
    </Context>
    ...
</Host>
```

Suppose that I've following servlet implementation:

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "MyServlet1",
    urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet1"}
)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyServlet1 extends HTTPServlet {
    ...
}
```

I've made a separate jar file which contains all of my servlet implementations and added it to `TOMCAT-HOME/lib` folder (Because it's used by several virtual hosts & I don't want to load it in the memory separately for every virtual host).

The problem is that when tomcat starts, I get this message it `catalina.out`:

> 02-Dec-2016 19:32:44.442 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/opt/tomcat/lib/MY-SERVLETS-IMPL.jar]. Consider adding the
>   JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property
>   in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

& when I want to access my servlet using address `my-domain.ir/MyServlet1` I get a 404 not found error page, but if I add servlet mapping in `web.xml` instead of using annotations, It works fine. In both cases my JSP files works fine.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In the conf/context.xml please add below code it may works

```
<JarScanner scanClassPath="false" />
```

By default scanAllDirectories, scanAllFiles, and scanBootstrapClassPath are set to false, but scanClassPath is true. So making it false may work.

If it does not work please let me know.

Aslo read [this](http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/how-to-get-your-tomcat-to-pounce-on-startup-not-crawl), it will help.

Comment: It had no effect & It still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Ehsan please read the link I have given.